# textAngular input field showing? Why?

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I am currently trying to implement the following [editor](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular).

Following [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xpn6hQjJcFKN483bzvqO?p=preview). Why is there an input field underneath the editor?

```
<div text-angular data-ng-model="htmlVariable">herro</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just seem to be missing the css file. Couldn't find a link to it so I just created a new stylesheet in plunkr and copied over the css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="textAngular.css">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bZ7HQqNEcDIuroWtxkfM

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the editor's css file.

Edit: [Link](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/src/textAngular.css) to the file, the class `.ta-hidden-input` hides the input element